# In Django, how to validate a (multiple) cholice field when the choices are added by Javascript?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `ChoiceField` where the choices are not known at the time the HTML is rendered; they are defined dynamically by the user and added to the form through Javascript, but the validation naturally fails since the selected option is not in the choices attribute (which is just an empty list). I have tried setting the field to a `CharField`, but then the validator just gets a string value that needs to be converted into a list before it van be used. Ah, and I'd like to avoid subclassing the field class as it's just for one occasion.

I hope this is clear. Any ideas?

Comment: So, what is actually the point of validating this field, since you do NOT want to check the value against known (predefined) list?

Comment: Well, there is a lot to validation apart from checking the list: correct type, uniqueness etc. However, it seems that I have ran into a small but potentially annoying Django bug; I've submitted it to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19643, so everyone is invited to check it out and let me know if I've completely missed the mark. :-)

Comment: @BerislavLopac I'm needing the same functionality. Did you ever solve this problem? If so, what did you do? I checked the submitted HTML and its submitting all of the values for the CharField, I just need to change the name of the field on the rendering of the form to include `[]` at the end of the field name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't subclass the field class but override the `clean_<yourfield>` method in your `Form` class. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Looking into the Django code, the `to_python` method on any `ChoiceField` subclass calls the `valid_value` method, which requires the `choices` to be non-empty. It seems that the only solution is to subclass the field. :-(

Comment: Ok, I answered too quickly. Maybe you could just cheat and change the `choices` attribute of your `ChoiceField` just before validating the form. That should work.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of that too, but apparently it's not that simple to hijack the choices validation; take a look at my response to migajek's comment above.